# How to turn my working JS jQuery from showing loading image for every new div to a global one

Tags: javascript, jquery

below is my working script that shows results on two divs, based on the selection of the drop down list.

Every time that the user selects, appears one loading image, for each div. 
Is there a way to have 1 loading image instead of 2 ? And when the pages are loaded, the image is removed.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#termid').change(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#firstresult').empty().addClass('loading').load(val + '.php', function(){$('#firstresult').removeClass('loading') });
    $('#secondresult').empty().addClass('loading').load(val + 'b.php', function(){$('#secondresult').removeClass('loading') });

    });
    });
```